# iconv conversion not supported

Tags: encoding

I'm not sure since when it happened, but it surely used to work before I upgraded to 14.04 (from 13.10) and now it doesn't:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t EUC-JP input > output
```

It gives me the following message:

```
iconv: conversion to `EUC-JP' is not supported
Try `iconv --help' or `iconv --usage' for more information.
```

I've tried EUCJP and I even tried a bunch of others listed in iconv -l, to no avail.
Something weird I've noticed is that iconv -l results in:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

about 50% of the time... not sure what's causing this.

I tried looking elsewhere, but couldn't find anything like this (most probably I've messed something up at some point ;P). Also iconv doesn't seem to be an apt package, so I'm not really sure if/how I should reconfigure it...

Thanks!

**EDIT: Not a very satisfying solution, but *uconv* works. Not sure what the difference between the two is.**

Answer (score 0):

Something is broken with your locales. Try this command,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still doesn't work though...
"Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_AU.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_BW.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IN.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NZ.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_PH.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_SG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZM.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZW.UTF-8... up-to-date
  ja_JP.UTF-8... up-to-date"
Only UTF-8, normal??

Comment: Yes, ubuntu is becommiing utf-8 only distro and for good reason. UTF-8 just works these days. I would advice against trying to get non-utf encoding. This is controlled by files in /var/lib/locales/supported.d, installed by package(s) language-pack-XX where XX is the language code.